# Help with Python script to query feature server

Tags: python, arcpy, feature-service

For the purpose of saving the data locally from a feature server online I have written code below:

```
import arcpy  
fcout = r'C:\Forum\Hydrants\test01.shp'  
url = 'http://gisweb.wsscwater.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/FireHydrant/FireBook/MapServer/0/query?text=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&objectIds=&where=1%3D1&time=&returnCountOnly=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&outSR=&outFields=*&f=pjson'  
fs = arcpy.FeatureSet()  
fs.load(url)  
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fs, fcout)
```

However only returns 1000 - there are 40000 data points, how would I create a shape file for the each of the other data points?

Comment: I won't pretend to be an authority on this, but a quick search indicates that the 1000 feature limit is the default, but expandable in the server settings. Is it your server?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @phloem's comment...this parameter is set when the feature service is published and can be modified (with appropriate permissions) in the Server Manager, in Desktop/Catalog, and the Server Admin directory.

You are looking for the **Maximum number of records returned by the server** parameter.  More detail on [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00sq0000009r000000) page under the "Parameters" subheading.

[image: Service Parameters]